# Apply CSS formatting to a paragraph if and only if it follows another paragraph

Tags: css, xhtml

What I would like to achieve it to apply via CSS some formatting settings to a paragraph only when the paragraph I am referring to is preceded by another paragraph. Examples:

```
<p>Something</p><p>FORMAT!</p>

<h1>Something</h1><p>DON'T FORMAT!</p>

<p>Something</p><ul><li>Something</li></ul><p>DON'T FORMAT!</p>
```

The only thing that matters is whether a paragraph is **immediately** preceded by another paragraph.

I can do this introducing a class to specify whether to apply the formatting or not (something like "first"), but I would like this analysis to be automated.

---

I already tried first-child without success, the third example would get formatted unless I add additional block structure which would defeat the purpose (then adding the custom class would be simpler...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
p + p {
    // formatting goes here
}
```

See **[adjacent selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)**.

Comment: This will format the last p. `<p>This won't be formatted</p><p>This will be formatted</p>`

Comment: @NaveedAhmad: This is what he asked for.

Comment: Thanks that's perfect! I completely ignored this CSS syntax (it was not mentioned in the book I used to study)